# Badge wrongly awarded to me? Bug in software?

Tags: bug, badges

I was awarded the Self-Learner badge for [How to say good-bye to an unhelpful and undisciplined professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45921/how-to-say-good-bye-to-an-unhelpful-and-undisciplined-professor/46033#46033)

The badge is defined "Answer your own question with score of 3 or more."

I didn't ask the how-to-say-good-bye question, so I suspect a bug.  But I wanted to check if I misunderstood something before I file a bug report.

1. Was this badge wrongly awarded?
2. To file a bug report, do I just email the team, or is there a better way?

Comment: As for point 2: Posting on this Meta (what you did) or [meta.se] is the default way to file a bug report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You posted that answer as a self-answer to a (now-deleted) "question" that you posted yourself "on behalf of" this OP. (The answer was later merged in to the original question by a moderator.) So it is a self-answer.

Comment: Another reminder how unreliable my memory is.  It wasn't even that long ago....